# dacwizard not found by import data access tier

Tags: azure-sql-database

Executing "Import Data-Tier Application" ,(without quotes) produces the error 
"object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacWizard)". Running DacWizard and creating the dacpac file in advance does not help. It is looking for the wizard. Since the wizard is there and I cannot effect it's location I am at a loss how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Could please try to download the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to eradicate that error? Please download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

If updating SSMS does not work, are you willing to try SqlPackage to import your bacpac.

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
C:\> .\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Import 
/SourceFile:"C:\Users\S\Desktop\MyDb.bacpac" 
/TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDb; Integrated Security=true;"
```